# Add file to angular project

Tags: angular

I want to add my Angular project to another project to put it into production. For that I did a ng build in my Angular project.

Then I add the 5 files to my production project like this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/inline.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/styles.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

I think I miss something for it to work. Is there not a sequence of numbers and letters to put after inline.bundle, or polyfills.bundle ... Like this for example ? :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js?b82bfbf37295902d0092"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js?b82bfbf37295902d0092"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js?b82bfbf37295902d0092"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js?b82bfbf37295902d0092"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js?b82bfbf37295902d0092"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js?b82bfbf37295902d0092"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing none` if you dont want the hash to be added to the bundle files.

Comment: But otherwise do you know where I could find this list of letters and numbers to add?

Comment: this is a hash that is generated by cli at time of build its random number i dont think you can change no sure @Floriane

Comment: It is not possible to find these numbers then?
Because the numbers I put in my post do not match mine, it was an example I found on the internet.

Comment: I think you cannot more info can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3885)

Comment: When I try your solution, I have this error : `Unhandled Promise rejection: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: The selector "app-root"`

Comment: i am using aot , its failing when doing aot compilation try and remove -- prod and --aot